# $refs is undefined when it's still working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm building a native hybrid app using Nuxt JS 2.9.1 and Vuetify JS. I have a notification component that is loaded into my `default.vue` layout just after the `<nuxt />` tag, this component is loaded into every page and triggers notifications using a Cordova plugin.

On each page, I'm making a HTTP GET request to a server, but for development it's a local JSON file, I'm using Axios to do this, however, I need to access an individual object from an array of many objects via it's index on each page to send to the notification component.

Since I'm unable to access each individual object index within my methods, I'm creating a hidden `<div>` containing a reference to each object based on the URL that a user is on, and am using a `ref` to access this in my methods.

However, I get the following error, despite it working correctly:

`Cannot read property '$refs' of undefined` and `Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined`

These errors seem to be inaccurate as it still appears to function.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(url, index) in dataUrls" :key="url.id">
      <div ref="getId">{{ index }}</div>
      <div ref="getUrl">{{ dataUrls[index].url }}</div>
      <div ref="getName">{{ dataUrls[index].name }}</div>
      <div ref="fetch">{{ dataUrls[index].fetchInterval }}</div>
      <div ref="muteNotifications">{{ dataUrls[index].muteNotifications }}</div>
      <div ref="notificationIcon">{{ dataUrls[index].notificationIcon }}</div>
      <div ref="notificationID">{{ dataUrls[index].notificationID }}</div>
    </div>
    <div v-for="(interval, index) in intervalData" :key="interval.id">
      <div ref="storedInterval">{{ intervalData[index].storedInterval }}</div>
      <div ref="running">{{ intervalData[index].running }}</div>
      <div ref="lastNotification">{{ intervalData[index].lastNotification }}</div>
      <div ref="lastUpdated">{{ intervalData[index].lastUpdated }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      defaultNotification: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.startFetchNotifications(), false)
  },
  methods: {

    /**
     * Fetch notifications
     */
    fetchNotification(key) {   
let self = this    self.axios.get(self.$refs.getUrl[key].innerText).then(function(response) {

        if (self.$refs.lastNotification[key].innerText === '') {
          self.intervalData[parseInt(self.$refs.getId[key].innerText)].lastNotification = response.data.notification
        }

        if (self.$refs.lastNotification[key].innerText != response.data.notification) {
          if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
            cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
              id: parseInt(self.$refs.notificationID[key].innerText),
              title: response.data.notification,
              text: self.$refs.getName[key].innerText,
              vibrate: false,
              priority: 1,
              badge: 0,
              foreground: true,
              sticky: true,
              sound: true,
              icon: 'file://' + self.$refs.notificationIcon[key].innerText,
              smallIcon: 'file://' + self.$refs.notificationIcon[key].innerText
            });
          } else {
            console.info('Native notification: ' + response.data.notification + ', won\'t run in the browser')
          }
          self.intervalData[parseInt(self.$refs.getId[key].innerText)].lastNotification = response.data.notification ? response.data.notification : ''
          self.intervalData[parseInt(self.$refs.getId[key].innerText)].lastUpdated = new Date()
        }
      })
    },


    /**
     * Fetch new notifications
     */
    autoFetchNotifications() {
      let self = this
      Object.keys(this.dataUrls).forEach(function(key, index) {

        // Interval updated
        if (parseInt(self.$refs.fetch[key].innerText) != parseInt(self.$refs.storedInterval[key].innerText)) {
          self.intervalData[parseInt(self.$refs.getId[key].innerText)].storedInterval = parseInt(self.$refs.fetch[key].innerText)

          // Stop running so we can start with new interval further down
          if (self.$refs.running[key].innerText != 'false') {
            clearInterval(parseInt(self.$refs.running[key].innerText))
            self.intervalData[parseInt(self.$refs.getId[key].innerText)].running = 'false'
          }
        }

        // If not running & not muted, then run
        if (self.$refs.running[key].innerText === 'false' && self.$refs.muteNotifications[key].innerText === 'false' && parseInt(self.$refs.fetch[key].innerText) > 0) {
          self.intervalData[parseInt(self.$refs.getId[key].innerText)].running = setInterval(() => {
            self.fetchNotification(key)
          }, parseInt(self.$refs.fetch[key].innerText))
        }

        // If running & muted, then stop
        if (self.$refs.running[key].innerText != 'false' && self.$refs.muteNotifications[key].innerText === 'true') {
          clearInterval(parseInt(self.$refs.running[key].innerText))
          self.intervalData[parseInt(self.$refs.getId[key].innerText)].running = 'false'
        }

      })
    }

  },
  computed: {
    dataUrls () {
      return this.$store.state.localStorage.dataUrls
    },
    intervalData () {
      return this.$store.state.localStorage.intervalData
    }
  },
  watch: {
    dataUrls: {
      handler: function (val, Oldval) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          console.log('fetch')
          this.autoFetchNotifications()
        }.bind(this), 10)
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Above is my notification component, loaded in every view.

How can I suppress this error, or what alternative can I implement here.

Comment: `self` is not declared (and hence `undefined`) in the `fetchNotification` method.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot this in my question. Although it exists in my code, but doesn't work

Comment: Where is your function `startFetchNotifications` declared?

Comment: This is a method within the same component, however I've taken it out for the purposes of reducing the code in my question, it's identical the others, except runs on page load

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.startFetchNotifications(), false)
```

by

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.startFetchNotifications, false)
```

to call the **startFetchNotifications** function when deviceready event listener is triggered, not when the event is created.

Answer (score -2):

you should avoid using $ref in vuejs ...

$ref is populated after the first dom render, so $ref is empty in mouted()

cf: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?#ref

Comment: Unless you can suggest an alternative/fix for my provided code, using `$refs` is my only option for my usecase

Comment: @RyanHolton While this response is wrong and there are many real usecases for using $refs, your code example isn't one of them.